# Retrieve unique entries from DB using Eloquent Laravel 4

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I am using `Laravel-4` to build an application. I am trying to make the best use of `Eloquent ORM`. Currently I am displaying a list of db entries which all have a number of tags associated with them
 To the right I display a grid of all the tags however it is showing duplicate tags. I would only like to show `unique` tags

This is my code:

```
<div class="tags-panel">
        <div class="tags-title"><h1>Tags</h1></div>
        <div class="tags-cloud">
            @foreach(Tag::distinct()->get() as $tag)
                <a href="#" class="tag"><span class="num"> {{ Tag::getAmount($tag->id) }} </span> {{$tag->name}} </a>
            @endforeach
        </div>
    </div>
```

Does `Eloquent` provide a way of only retrieving `distinct` entries from the db?

Comment: It seems that your code runs a lot of unnecessary queries. You need probably something like `lists`, but show your table and what result you expect, in order to get real answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try using Tag::groupBy('field_name')->get()

```
<div class="tags-panel">
    <div class="tags-title"><h1>Tags</h1></div>
        <div class="tags-cloud">
            @foreach(Tag::groupBy('field_name')->get() as $tag)
                <a href="#" class="tag"><span class="num"> {{ Tag::getAmount($tag->id) }} </span> {{$tag->name}} </a>
            @endforeach
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To use the `distinct()`-function you have either have a `select()` in your chain, or use a field as an argument in your `get()`-function. For example:

```
$tags = Tag::distinct()->get(array('field'));
```

or

```
$tags = Tag::select('field')->distinct()->get();
```

You could also instead use `groupBy('field')` if you don't want to supply field names:

```
$tags = Tag::groupBy('field')->get();
```